# Excel random number formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to generate acronyms consisting of the letter "i" + a random number between 1 and 7.
Currently I do it with this formula:

```
= CONCAT ("i"; RANDBETWEEN (1; 7))
```

For example the output can be i4.

Then I need to generate a second abbreviation, but the following number "i" must be different from the previous one, therefore from i1 to i7 excluding i4.
I have tried several formulas but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Excel 365** and the US Locale, in a cell enter:

```
="i" & SORTBY(SEQUENCE(7),RANDARRAY(7))
```

[image]